# instagram developer API gett 400,"error_message

Tags: api, instagram, developer-tools

I am sending URL and I'm getting: {"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthPermissionsException","code":400,"error_message":"This client has not been approved to access this resource."}}

I have the privilege and everything seems fine
And of course could not see more than 20 pictures. I made a script that should 
give proceed to the next page but it does not work.

Any ideas what could be done? It's really important
Thanks friends.

I have permission is basic . I see 20 images of any user public . If I want to see more pictures ( next page ), then I see the error I mentioned . I ask to see images only

Comment: can u show us the code?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you have the right permission approved to access the endpoint you are trying to access.

What API call are you making?

Which permissions does your app have?

- basic
- comments
- follower_list
- likes
- public_content
- relationships

Comment: I have permission is basic . I see 20 images of any user public . If I want to see more pictures ( next page ), then I see the error I mentioned .
I ask to see images only .

Comment: u need `public_content ` permission for it